# How To Add More Than 1 Select Sections as DataSource in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

As below `procedure` it has two select sections (`type=1` and `type=2`). I am binding Crystal Report with this procedure. Both the sections has to bind to report. `type=1` gives multiple rows & `type=2` gives single row. First i have to bind report with `type=2` then with `type=1` on same report. But on selecting this procedure as `DataSource` in Crystal Report it is picking only `type=1` select method as `DataSource`. How should I include both `types` in procedure as `DataSource` in Report?
I am using CrystalReport in VS2008.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_report]
 @applicationno varchar(20)=null,
 @sessionyr varchar(10)=null,
 @type int=null
as
BEGIN
     
     if(@type=1)
       begin
                /* Select Statement Goes Here */
       end    
    if(@type=2)
       begin
                /* Select Statement Goes Here */
       end
               
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use more than one resultset from a stored proc in Crystal. You could adjust your proc, so that it delivers same columns for both types (and fill only the used ones, of course).